# Quickest/best way to copy a portion of a large mongo database to another server?

Tags: mongodb

I have a dataset of 100m tweets stored in Mongo, unoptimized and unindexed.

I need to copy all tweets from the last month onto another server, what is the best way to do this?

My idea was to use a Ruby script to extract and copy the relevant tweets to a new database on the server, then run the mongo copyDatabase command to copy it over. Its taking horrendously long though, any other way to do it?

```
require 'mongo_mapper'
MongoMapper.database = 'twitter'
require './models'
tweets = TwitterTweet.where(:created_at => {"$gt" => 1.month.ago}).all; # about 15 million

MongoMapper.database = 'monthly'
# copy the tweets over to the new db
tweets.each do |tweet|
  tweet.save!
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need your data on the several servers you just should use mongodb replication features.
If you just want to backup your data, then the quickest way will by just copy db files.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- Adding multiple clients/threads to do the processing/saving (maybe each one work on a single day's tweets for example just to make it simple). Continue to add clients until the server is at capacity.
- Copy the entire database to the new server and remove the old data, then [compact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/) it (and index it).
- Consider disabling journaling (if that's safe for your needs), or tuning it to write [less frequently](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--journalCommitInterval) (less durability)
- Ensure any logging, tracing, etc. is disabled
- Make sure the server is adaquately sized to handle load
- Or, just take a long holiday while it completes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the database files to a new host, start mongod and delete the documents / drop databases / collections you don't need. That's the quickest way.